# Zend Framework 1.x git repository

Tags: git, zend-framework, github

Is there any official (or always up to date) Zend Framework 1.x git repository?
(ZF 1.11.3 was released yesterday)

I have found only [ZF2 github repo](https://github.com/zendframework) so far.

Comment: One, unofficial unfortunately, is at https://github.com/svenax/ZendFramework/tree/release-1.11. At the moment they have only ZF 1.11.2 but maybe soon they will have 1.11.3.

Comment: @marcin Here is another one, but not up to date too: https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror

Comment: ZF1 is moving to Github (though it is also approaching End-Of-Life status) - http://framework.zend.com/blog//2013-03-27-zf1-git-migration.html & https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/ (announced March 27th, 2013)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [May 2013](http://framework.zend.com/blog/2013-03-27-zf1-git-migration.html) [Zend Framework 1](http://github.com/zendframework/zf1) has been migrated to GitHub.

Thank you, Trendfischer.

Comment: The answer is not right any more. Zend Frameworks moved on 4/2013 according to this Blog article: http://framework.zend.com/blog/2013-03-27-zf1-git-migration.html and the Github URI is https://github.com/zendframework/zf1

Answer (score 4):

There is no official ZF1 Git repository but there is a Git mirror provided by our company: https://github.com/komola/ZendFramework there are tags for the newest versions. (starting with 1.11.11)

Comment: It does not look like that this is been keeping up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

Zend won't move the version 1 for Git. The version 2 is being developed on Git https://github.com/zendframework/zf2 .

Non-officially, I have a repo on Github which contains only the library path ( https://github.com/dmelo/Zend-1.11 ). I use it with git submodule on the projects I develop. You can clone this repository using the url [git://github.com/dmelo/Zend-1.11.git](http://git://github.com/dmelo/Zend-1.11.git)

This Github repository is updated daily with the commits from the official subversion repository.

Comment: Update: Zend WILL move ZF1 to github http://framework.zend.com/blog/2013-03-27-zf1-git-migration.html